# How to manage alternate lines with 2 different styles in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I want to create a note taking editor in ace.

For e.g. i paste some spanish text in the editor. I then want to note down english words for some corresponding spanish words. I want these english words to appear above the respective spanish words( in between 2 lines in spanish)

So what i will ve is alternate lines in my editor with 2 text styles. Spanish in bigger and english in smaller font.

How do i do this?
I think ace uses contenteditable.
How do i formst alternate lines in different styles?

Answer (score 0):

Ace doesn't use contenteditable, and supports only monospace fonts so you'll have to add variable size font support to ace which isn't easy.